# Cannot run ruby commands while running Docker

Tags: ruby, docker

I have an image I have built with Ruby in it. I am able to run Ruby commands, `irb` and `install gems` in the image while running by:

```
docker run -it jikkujose/apple
```

I can also do this to list the files in the container:

```
docker run -it jikkujose/apple ls
```

But when I try to run Ruby commands, it fails:

```
docker run -it jikkujose/apple ruby -e "puts 'Hello'"
```

Error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container c888aa8d2c7510a672608744a69f00c5feda4509742d54ea2896b7ebce76c16d: [8] System error: exec: "ruby": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: Its possible PATH is not set correctly use the complete path of the binary `/usr/bin/ruby` or try `/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/ruby  -e "puts 'Hello'"` make sure the path is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because the ruby executable is not in the path of the user running the container process (i.e. `root` or the user specified with the USER command in the Dockerfile). The following two options might help you with your problem.

1. Specify the full path to the ruby binary when running the container. `docker run -it jikkujose/apple /usr/bin/ruby -e "puts 'Hello'"`
2. Add `/usr/bin` to the path in the Dockerfile `ENV PATH /usr/bin:$PATH` I'm not 100% sure this works, but the ENV operator in the Dockerfile should add this environment variable to the container. Source [docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/).

Alternatively you can specify `/usr/bin/ruby` as the `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile. That is: `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/ruby"]`. Then you can run `docker run -it jikkujose/apple -e "puts 'Hello'"` Note that this causes  the container to run /usr/bin/ruby as default, and that you need to override this entrypoint if you want to run `ls` or other commands.

Edit:

Minimal viable `Dockerfile` solution is given below. Let us assume that /usr/bin is not already in the $PATH environment variable, which it is in the Ubuntu image.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get install ruby -y

ENV PATH /usr/bin:$PATH

CMD ["bash"]
```

Running `docker run --rm -it pathtest ruby -e "puts 'Hello'"` now outputs `Hello` in the terminal.

Edit 2:

Ah, you built the image with Docker commit. You can send in environment variables when running the `docker run` command. To do this simply run docker like so:

```
docker run --rm -e "PATH=/usr/bin" -it pathtest ruby -e "puts 'Hello'"
```

The -e option for `docker run` lets you specify or override an environment variable inside the container. Note that you will have to provide all paths you want $PATH to equal with this method.

You may also want to simply edit the PATH variable inside the container and then recommit the container so that /usr/bin is present in the $PATH environment variable stored in the container.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to run: `docker run -it jikkujose/apple whoami` and got `root` as the response; the same user when I login to this container. It seems the problem is that the `PATH` isn't getting set. If I am running the container from command line how can I endure path is set?

Comment: Added minimal viable Dockerfile in the answer above.

Comment: Added example of how you can specify environment variables as options to the docker run command.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible `PATH` is not set correctly, therefore try

> docker run -it jikkujose/apple /usr/bin/ruby -e "puts 'Hello'"

or

> docker run -it jikkujose/apple /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/ruby -e "puts
>   'Hello'"

Comment: Providing `PATH` of the Ruby executable does indeed work. But I would like to know why the `PATH` isn't getting set. Curiously, `running: docker run -it jikkujose/apple echo $PATH` gives my own machine's `PATH` variable rather than the container's! Why is it so?

Comment: Interestingly, when I login and echo the `PATH` variable I get it right too!

Comment: Then you may want to check the dockerfile, if your PATH is getting overwritten while building the image. Next check the base images docker file just to confirm.

Comment: I don't have a Dockerfile as I created this image via `docker commit`; any way to have the `PATH` via command line?